# Error "cannot resolve ProgressBarDeterminate"

Tags: android

I have used ProgressBarDeterminate and have used some of its properties, but it shows me error saying cannot resolve ProgressBarDeterminate

Comment: that's because there is no such thing as `ProgressBarDeterminate` in Android SDK.

Comment: I think you mean to use this library: https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary

If this is the case you can follow the instructions here: https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary#how-to-use

Answer (score 0):

use below code

```
  <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar"
  style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
```

java file

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);  //for visible progress
        progressBar.setProgress(0); 
        progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);  //invisible

    }
```